# How to Tell if Folder is Indexed

Tags: windows-7, search

Is there an easy way to tell if Windows has indexed a folder or not (Windows 7). Or, is there a list of all indexed folders?

Comment: Looking at the already given answers, I think the actual question of the user is not which folders are marked for indexing, but instead 'which folders are marked for indexing, but are still in the queue to be indexed'. As far as I know, Windows 7 only shows you whether it has completely indexed all folder, or not. But Matt wants to find  out (IMO) which *specific* folders have not yet been indexed, and which have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control Panel -> Indexing Options

This is where to find a list of all indexed folders.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft; [source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Change-advanced-indexing-options)

1. Open Indexing Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type indexing options, and then click Indexing Options.
2. Click Advanced. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. In the Advanced Options dialog box, click the File Types tab.
4. In the Add new extension to list box, type the file name extension (for example, "txt"), and then click Add.
5. Click Index Properties Only or Index Properties and File Contents, and then click OK.